# Proyecto de una rama de git?

Tags: github

Como descargo(clone) y subo cambios a una rama en git?

hace tiempo que use git, para bajar la ultima version usaba

```
git -pull
```

y para subir mis cambios lo hacia con

```
git push
```

pero lo sobreescribia los cambios a los cambios que hacia mi amigo, entonces como hago para que trabaje en sincronía?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para trabajar con ramas el procedimiento es el siguiente:

Si no tienes la rama bajada:

```
git clone -b nombre-rama https://github.com/nombre-repositorio
```

Si ya tienes la carpeta con la rama bajada:

```
git pull
```

(solo hace falta hacer pull ya que el .git ya sabe que estas trabajando con la rama)

Haces todos los cambios que quieras.

Para subirlo sencillamente haces:

```
git add . #puedes cambiar el '.' por el/los fichero/s concreto que quieras.
git commit -m "Descripción de tus cambios"
git push
```

Ten en cuenta que entre que haces pull y push, si tu compañero realiza algun cambio en la rama y lo sube, entrará en conflicto con la última version que te bajaste y no te dejará subirlo. Entonces tendrías que hacer un pull para copiar los últimos cambios de tu compañero de nuevo.

Comment: como llego a la rama?

Comment: Al añadir "-b nombre-de-tu-rama" al commando clone ya te baja solo la rama. A partir de ahí todos los cambios que hagas los harás sobre la rama únicamente.

Comment: Si ya tienes la rama bajada anteriormente, tienes que llegar a la carpeta de la rama. E.j. en linux "cd $HOME/Dektop/nombre-de-repositorio". Si tienes el repositorio bajado en el escritorio.

Comment: cuando uso checkout?, pense que era para llegar a la rama, y para hacer cambios parciales usar merge

Comment: Parece que tu conocimiento de git es muy basico, te recomiendo leer el libro de Git, se lee en una tarde haciendo ejemplos y tu conocimiento sera muy solido al respecto. Git tiene muchas mas bondades. http://librosweb.es/libro/pro_git/

Comment: @PedroAdameVergara por eso pregunto, ando leyendo y tengo dudas

Comment: @deluf El enlace que te he proporcionado explica detalladamente el funcionamiento de git, desde basico hasta avanzado. Con dedicarle unas horas a la lectura y practica de los ejemplos, tendras un conocimiento sólido de git y podrás solventar tanto esta duda como la mayoría que te puedan surgir. "Dale un pez a un hombre y come un dia, dale una caña y enseñale a pescar y comera siempre"